# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following code shows error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null"`

```
  <style>
      .deactive { height:250px; }
      .active { height:150px; }
  </style>
  <script>
      function click(div) {
          document.getElementById('div').className  = 'active';
      }
  </script>
  <a href="#" onclick="click(Division);">
      <div id="Division" class="deactive">
          <!--Division contents-->
      </div>
  </a>
```

i am trying pass id of division to js function by on click event of anchor tag.. and i want to change the class name of the division, 
help me to identify the error..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error occurs because in your document you have no elements whose id is `"div"` so `document.getElementById('div')` is `null`.

You need to change here:

```
onclick="click('division');"
```

use quotes around argument, and

```
document.getElementById(div).className  = 'active';
```

`div` here must not be enclosed in quotes, since you're using the parameter passed when the function has been called

(as a side note: avoid to call your function `click`)

example [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HgcGV/)

Comment: div here must not be enclosed in quotes ?? But you yourself said that there is no element with this id. So why should he use it ?

Comment: `div` inside the function is the variable whose value is `"division"` when you call the function... try to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions